# sees no OpenCV module How to specify the path to the python module

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

sees no OpenCV module
I installed the module folder OpenCV / build
Moved OpenCV in the folder Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely but if you have Anaconda installed you can download OpenCV using the following command:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv=2.4.11
```